# Pick a file using native Windows picker on a Jenkins master (headless) node

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

I have Selenium test which picks a file via native Windows file picker window. This is achieved by using Java [Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class. This works fine when the test runs with a normal session (i.e. with a GUI). However when running test on a Jenkins master node tests are performed from other user and there is no active desktop session in this case, and files cannot be picked.

Is there a way to deal with this without setting slave node with a GUI?

There are lot of articles which suggest all the same ways to deal with file picking, but none mention about dealing with Windows native file picker when running a test from master node (with different user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Robot** can't be used in a headless environment. It's a known limitation. So you have to use active desktop mode. The same is valid for tools like SikuliX / AutoIT.